# loading only the perticular view file in magento without header and footer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

if i do follow thing from controller

```
$this->loadLayout();     
$this->renderLayout();
```

And following in that layout file

```
<label>Label</label>
<remove name="right" />
<remove name="left" />
<remove name="header" />
<remove name="footer" />
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="abc/abc" name="hello" template="abc/abc.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Is there any way to load the particular view file without loading the header and footer of the magento. I do not want any kinds of css, js loading on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento, the 'head' block is responsible, amongst other things, for js and css output.  So, the only code you have missing from the layout xml provided is the following:

```
<remove name="head" />
```

Also, you have not provided the layout handles in the sample code.  Make sure that you are targeting the correct layout handle.

Comment: 1 shot and really good answer. Hand on to you. Thank you. Worked.